# Changing CruiseControl.net service account

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I've been using cruisecontrol.net as a service account. Recently we changed the account password, and from then cruisecontrol web page will not load.
It says -

Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

After changing the credentials, I changed the log-on details of the service in services.msc.
I changed the logon details in IIS also.
But still the same error is coming up.

Am I missing something?
Can anyone share me the complete steps to be followed while changing the service account credentials of cruisecontrol.net.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart the service and IIS after configuring the new password?

Comment: yes I had done that. still the error came..

Comment: The issue got resolved.
I checked the event viewer logs and it says
"Cruisecontrol application pool is not started"

I went back to IIS, took the application pools list, changed the logon credentials for the CruiseControl application pool, and started the application pool.
After an IISreset, it works fine.. :) :)